# Can I insert new record to QSqlRelationalTableModel with new foreign id?

Tags: python, sqlite, qt, pyqt

### What I am trying to do

I have tables `member` and `account`. Each member has two accounts, which are two foreign accounts ids.

When a user creates a new member (clicks the post button and triggers `model.submitAll()`), I want the program to create the **two member accounts first**, then create the **member using the new account ids**.

So far, I have a working form and relational model that shows the members and their accounts (tested using pre-made data).

With the [`beforeInsert(record)`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtSql/QSqlTableModel.html#PySide6.QtSql.PySide6.QtSql.QSqlTableModel.beforeInsert) signal, I create the new accounts, get the new account ids, and set the member `record`'s account id fields. However, member record cannot be inserted. I get a `NULL Constraint` error. At this point, the new accounts are in the database, but no member is made. If I restart my program, thereby calling the `QSqlRelationalTableModel.select()` again, and try to make a new member, two new accounts are made (again of course) and the member is successfully created and has the two new account ids.

### TLDR here is the actual problem

I cannot insert new records into a [`QSqlRelationalTableModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtSql/QSqlRelationalTableModel.html) if the foreign table has no records (with or without the NULL constraint, btw).

### Code

**In parent class (t_member_widget) where the model is made, aka the working code**

```
def makeModel(self):
        self.model = QSqlRelationalTableModel()
        self.model.setTable("t_member")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)

        self.model.setRelation(7, QSqlRelation("t_account", "id", "account_name"))
        self.model.setRelation(6, QSqlRelation("t_account", "id", "account_name"))
        self.model.setJoinMode(QSqlRelationalTableModel.LeftJoin)
        self.model.select()
```

**In child class, where everything works but it errors anyway**

```
class memberHandler(t_member_widget_form_wtbl.t_member_widget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.redoConnections()

    def redoConnections(self):
        self.model.beforeInsert.connect(self.make_member_accounts)

    def make_member_accounts(self, record):
        member_name = record.value("name")
        query = QSqlQuery()
        # ... successfully inserts 2 records into account table
        query.exec()

        draw_id, cap_id = get_most_recent_account_ids()
        # THESE TWO LINES BELOW WORK
        record.setValue("capital_account", cap_id)
        record.setValue("drawing_account", draw_id)
        # BUT THEN RECORD IS NOT INSERTED BECAUSE NULL CONSTRAINT ERROR
```

Please let me know what clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

### My solution

Prepopulate my `account` table with a DO NOT USE account, the then above code works perfectly. I do not understand why this works. It probably has something to do with the table join, but I cannot explain it.

I was not able to find other articles about this issue. I hope someone has a better answer because I don't like my solution very much.